# Help Identifying Italian track frame

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage

Hi I would like to know the maker of this bike I brought back from my stay in Italy. It has been repainted, It isn't the original fork, and the serial located on the top of th bb is :1148591
Any clue ? Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you think the fork is not original?  Its got the 80's rake and looks correct.  There's a brake mounting bolt there, but no caliper.

Comment: Also, the amount of paint skuffing suggests any repaint was long ago.  What makes you think it was repainted?

Comment: This frame is older than 80's. Check the cottered cranks, shallow angles and long chainstays. The fork has drilling for brake and fender eyelets, both of which don't belong on a track bike. The frame doesn't have eyelets, unfortunately the photos don't show if the seatstay bridge has been drilled.

Comment: @Criggie Thanks for the response. I'm sorry you're right, it's the original paint. I meant the fork has been repainted, I noticed a green layer underneath and the guy who sold me the bike told me he replaced it, also the tint of the blue is slightly different.

Comment: @ojs I could upload the picture but yes the seatstay bridge is drilled

Answer (score 1):

This could be pretty much anything, you might want to find a specialist in lugworks. Many Italian frame makers had very unique lugging to determine their bikes from the rest. I used to know a few by heart back in the days when I was restoring old racers for [Single Speed Co](https://single-speed.co.uk/) but I'm afraid that skill has fallen back now. Having unique lugs was especially important on older bikes. 
I can't see on the photos what is happening between rear dropouts, it could be an old track frame but some older bikes never had the horizontal dropouts so it could just be an old frame designed as a single speed bike. It definitely looks older than 80's and even 70's are still questionable.

How is the weight on this?

Comment: The lugwork isn't the puzzling part. What's puzzling is the seatpost clamp **in front of** the seatpost instead of behind it, in combination with the lugwork. I know of a manufacturer known for their lugwork who also had a striped seat tube like that, but they've had their clamps behind the seatpost since at least the 1950s.

Comment: That is indeed very interesting. Sadly I won't be able to help with this but it is a very interesting frame you have there.